# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED , mocha , supertest

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm new  to  mocha and supertest , I'm trying to test  my API but I always get  connection refused error  .

```js
  
var request = require('supertest');

 it("posts a new comment to /comment", function (done) {
    var comment = { username: 'riheb', userId: 'test1', userPhotoId: '12a', comment: 'update file  now' };

    request("http://localhost:3000")
      .post("/sp/place/582f148515035818e080e653/folder/582f16b3ef9caf029863331b/file/583d6b5243af5628b8491fd3/comment")
      .send(comment)
      .expect(200)
      .expect(" riheb comment is stored", done);
  });
});
```

Could you give any clue why this happend? 
 With Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) library, you have to *expose* and *inject* your app (`express`) not a url (because you won't have an active server listening):

```
var request = require('supertest');
var app = require('../yourappexposed');

describe("Comments", function() {
 it("posts a new comment to /comment", function (done) {
    var comment = { username: 'riheb', userId: 'test1', userPhotoId: '12a', comment: 'update file  now' };
    request(app)
      .post("/sp/place/582f148515035818e080e653/folder/582f16b3ef9caf029863331b/file/583d6b5243af5628b8491fd3/comment")
      .send(comment)
      .expect(200)
      .expect(" riheb comment is stored", done);
    });
  });
});
```